# Big notation for an algorithm efficiency

Tags: algorithm, big-o

can anyone help me to identify the steps for the following example and  give more explanation on this Example the steps That determine Big-O notation is O(2<sup>n</sup>)

```
int i, j = 1;
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
     j = j * 2;
}  

for(i = 1; i <= j; i++)
{
     cout << j << "\n";
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: What will be the value of j after the first loop. How many times will the second loop execute?

Answer (score 1):

The first loop has n iterations and assigns 2^n to j.

The second loop has j = 2^n iterations.

The cout has time complexity O(log j) = O(n).

Hence the overall complexity is O(n * 2^n), which is strictly larger than O(2^n).

Comment: Why are you ascribing runtime to the cout? Seems that the 1st loop is n, 2nd loop is 2^n, for a total of O(n + 2^n) or O(2^n).

Comment: @tar You can't copy n characters onto a stream in less than n steps. Now consider how many characters are copied in total: it's O(n*2^n).